# Android Jetpack Compose: Default Font Family is Not Applied to Text()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I set the Cursive font family as the default one in the Type.kt file:

```
package com.example.composeproject.ui.theme

import androidx.compose.material.Typography
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp


val Typography = Typography(
    defaultFontFamily = FontFamily.Cursive, // the default is cursive font
    body1 = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = 16.sp
    )
    /* Other default text styles to override
    button = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.W500,
        fontSize = 14.sp
    ),
    caption = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = 12.sp
    )
    */
)
```

Theme.kt file:

```
package com.example.composeproject.ui.theme

import androidx.compose.foundation.isSystemInDarkTheme
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Shapes
import androidx.compose.material.darkColors
import androidx.compose.material.lightColors
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable

private val DarkColorPalette = darkColors(
    primary = Purple80,
    secondary = PurpleGrey80
)

private val LightColorPalette = lightColors(
    primary = Purple40,
    secondary = PurpleGrey40

    /* Other default colors to override
    background = Color(0xFFFFFBFE),
    surface = Color(0xFFFFFBFE),
    onPrimary = Color.White,
    onSecondary = Color.White,
    onTertiary = Color.White,
    onBackground = Color(0xFF1C1B1F),
    onSurface = Color(0xFF1C1B1F),
    */
)

@Composable
fun ComposeProjectTheme(darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(), content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkColorPalette
    } else {
        LightColorPalette
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = Typography,
        shapes = Shapes(),
        content = content
    )
}
```

MainActivity.kt code:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import com.example.composeproject.ui.theme.ComposeProjectTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            ComposeProjectTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    Column {
                        Text(
                            text = "Test Text"
                        )
                        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                            Text(text = "Click Me")
                        }
                    }
                    //MainScreen()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

As you can see the Cursive is applied to `Button()` text, but not the `Text()`. Anyone is facing the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You immediately override `body1` style which is used by `Text` with `fontFamily = FontFamily.Default`, hence the default style. `Button` uses `button` text style which you don't override.

You could either remove `body1` override entirely or define `fontFamilty` for it too:

```
    defaultFontFamily = FontFamily.Cursive,
    body1 = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = FontFamily.Cursive,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = 16.sp
    )
```

Comment: Correct. I have no idea how I missed it. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided seems generally well-structured. However, I've noticed a small inconsistency in the ComposeProjectTheme function where you are using the Typography object without importing it. Ensure that you import the Typography object at the beginning of the file. Here's the corrected ComposeProjectTheme function:

```
 fun ComposeProjectTheme(darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(), content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkColorPalette
    } else {
        LightColorPalette
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = Typography, // Import Typography
        shapes = Shapes(),
        content = content
    )
}
```